# Number systems converter doesn't work on a specific compiler (Dev-C++)

Tags: c++, c, converters

choice number 3 (Decimal to Binary) It works on Code:Blocks to be specific, haven't tried on Visual C++, but our school uses Dev-C++, I can't figure out what causes the problem. I mean it's logically and syntactically correct.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#define MAXDIGITS 100

void printmenu(void);
void getchoice(void);
void decitobinary(int str);



int main(void)
{
    char choice;

    printmenu();
    getchoice();
    system("cls");
    while(1)
    {
        printf("\nAgain? y/n: ");
        scanf("\n%c",&choice);
        if(choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y')
        {
            system("cls");
            main();
        }
        else if(choice == 'n' || choice == 'N')
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        else
        {
            printf("\a\nInvalid input.\n");
            continue;
        }
    }
}

void printmenu(void)
{
    printf("\n3 - Decimal -> Binary");
    printf("\n19 - Exit Program\n");
}

void getchoice(void)
{
    int choice;
    char number[MAXDIGITS];
    int digits;

    printf("\nEnter choice: ");
    scanf("\n%d",&choice);
    switch(choice)
    {

        case 3:
        {
            system("cls");
            printf("Enter number: ");
            scanf("\n%d",&digits);
            decitobinary(digits);
            break;
        }

        case 19:
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
}


void decitobinary(int str)
{
    int arraycntr = 0;
    int number[arraycntr];
    printf("\n%d in binary is: ",str);
    while(str > 0)
    {
        number[arraycntr] = str % 2;
        str /= 2;
        ++arraycntr;
    }
    for(arraycntr -= 1;arraycntr >= 0;arraycntr--)
    {
        printf("%d",number[arraycntr]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Uh... that's a lot of code...

Comment: That's a lot and lots of code to look at..can you bring it down to small piece of code that shows the problem.. at first glance this doesn't look right to me: `int arraycntr = 0; int number[arraycntr];` you have an array with `0` size.

Comment: By the way: **what's the actual problem?** We can't just magically guess for you.

Comment: Wait, ill change it, I thought I didn't have to cut it because the only problem was it doesnt work on a specific compiler.

Comment: Shortened it. Although its still choice 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void decitobinary(int str)
{
    int arraycntr = 0;
    int number[arraycntr];
    printf("\n%d in binary is: ",str);
    while(str > 0)
    {
        number[arraycntr] = str % 2;
        str /= 2;
        ++arraycntr;
    }
    for(arraycntr -= 1;arraycntr >= 0;arraycntr--)
    {
        printf("%d",number[arraycntr]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    system("pause");
}
```

Problem is in initialization of *number* array. It should be something like:

```
int number[33];
```

33 places is enough to store all binary digits.

Comment: i dont get it? i declared it as int number[MAXDIGITS]; and i defined MAXDIGITS as 100 which is more than enough

Comment: You declared it in getchoice() function, not in decitobinary.

Comment: @vincentbelkin: What are you talking about? Look at the code you posted yourself. You declared the array as `int number[arraycntr]`, which is equivalent to `int number[0]`. This is the problem, at least one of them. Your `char number[MAXDIGITS]` is in a completely different function and it is not even used, so it is completely irrelevant (what's the purpose of it?). The problematic `number` array is in `decitobinary` function.

Comment: Ughhhhhhh, thanks man, I kinda got confused in that one. Typed in arraycntr instead of MAXDIGITS

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer.  Just something to consider.  You have about 10 identical implementations for the same function!  Have you considered just consolidating all variations of decitobase and basetodeci into a single pair of functions:

```
void decitobase(int str, int base)
{
    int arraycntr = 33;
    int number[arraycntr] = {};
    printf("\n%d in base %d is: ",str, base);
    while(str > 0)
    {
        number[arraycntr] = str % base;
        str /= base;
        ++arraycntr;
    }
    for(arraycntr -= 1;arraycntr >= 0;arraycntr--)
    {
        printf("%d",number[arraycntr]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    system("pause");
}

void basetodeci(char str[], int base)
{
    int arraycntr,digitcntr,power;
    int value[MAXDIGITS];
    int number;
    arraycntr = 0;
    digitcntr = 0;
    number = 0;
    power = 1;
    while(str[arraycntr] != '\0')
    {
        value[arraycntr] = str[arraycntr] - '0'
        ++arraycntr;
    }
    digitcntr = arraycntr - 1;
    for(digitcntr; digitcntr >= 0; digitcntr--)
    {
        number += value[digitcntr] * power;
        power *= base;
    }
    printf("\n%s base %d in decimal is: %ld\n",str,base,number);
    system("pause");
 }
```

I don't know if the above code is any more correct than what you've submitted, but I hope you see what I'm getting at.
 Also don't forget there is a C function that will convert strings to integers within any base you want: [strtol](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) and friends.

Comment: Oh! Thanks! Sorry I probably dont have quite a good programmers logic yet, but will try to do this in my next code!

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm you are using is very slow. Instead, since you are dealing with binary numbers, use the bit-wise operators.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BITS_N  (sizeof(unsigned int) * 8)
#define MSB     (1 << (BITS_N - 1))


void print_binary (unsigned int val)
{
  for(size_t i=0; i<BITS_N; i++)
  {
    printf("%c", (val & MSB) ? '1' : '0' );
    val <<= 1;

    if( ((i+1)%8) == 0) // print a space every 8th digit
    {
      printf(" ");
    }

  }
}


int main()
{
  unsigned int some_val = 0xBAADBEEF;

  print_binary (some_val);
}
```